# Ordering the results from a junction table based on values of the row its foreign key belongs to

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have three tables for a many-to-many: Authors, Authorships, Books. I would like to select rows from authorship and order it alphabetically according to the author this row belongs to.
Example:

```
-- Authors --
ID   Name
1    Peter
2    Gregory
3    Daniel

-- Authorships--
ID   AuthorId    BookId
1    1           1
2    2           1
3    3           1

-- Books--
ID   Name
1    Foobook
```

I would like to write a select statement that returns all rows from authorship belonging to a specific book then orders the result by author name.

So something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Authorships WHERE BookId = 1 ORDER BY (Authors.Name???);
```

Except I need to order the result.
I understand how this question might look silly because of its workaround/inefficient nature, but I am working with a lot of legacy code and am not allowed to really change anything else.

Thank you.

Comment: You have to `JOIN` with `Authors` table to get `Name`. Then you can put that `Name` in `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
SELECT auth.* FROM Authorships auth, Authors au, Books bk WHERE auth.BookId = bk.ID and auth.AuthorId = au.ID ORDER BY au.Name
```

SQLFiddle Link:
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37c2d/4/0)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the fast answer, I managed to port it to my db and it works perfectly. However, it is a bit more complicated: I have one more column in the junction table called contributor: therefore a row defines either an author or a contributor like this: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/251a4/1)

Comment: what do you want now?

Comment: I expanded your code a bit, but now I get one row multiple times. Other than doing group by, is there a better solution in your opinion? (sry for wall of text)

Comment: can you tell me which row is multiple time?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I removed the group by ID, so it is duplicated again. Now it looks like this: [link](http://i.imgur.com/Hvn7hb9.png) Thanks and know that I really appreciate all the time and effort you are spending on helping me.

Comment: why did you remove group by?

Comment: It seems to me that the number of duplicate rows grows exponentially with the table size, so group by only works on small tables. I would like to understand why it happens and treat the problem from there.

Comment: group by is necessary

Comment: You know what? You are right, I should definitely try. Thanks for all, you are a life saver :)